# How to get selected item group name in "loudev" multi-select

Tags: jquery, multi-select

For Ex:

[image]

If select 'Yoda' I want to get that group name 'Friends' in the loudev afterSelect method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I got a solution. The above ref image is lou-dev multi-select rendered elements.

So first we find selected item element with that name.

Next we get that near by li with `.ms-optgroup-label` class name

The code ref:

```
afterSelect: (selectedVals) => { //selectedVals=[Yoda]
  $(`span:contains('${selectedVals[0]}')`).first().closest('li').siblings('li.ms-optgroup-label').text()
}
```